# Spring Security successHandler not called after successfully logging in - Return Code 302

Tags: spring, spring-security

After successfull login (user is redirected to the page defined in defaultSuccessUrl), status code 302 is returned. It seems that the successHandler is not called. I would like to get the status code 200.
The authentication works fine using UI, but I need it also for REST API calls.
Here are the code snipets:

**Configuration**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/console/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .successHandler(mySuccessHandler)
    .failureUrl("/console")
    .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
    .and()
    .logout()
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .permitAll();

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/jobs.xhtml", true);

    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml");

}
```

**MvcConfiguration**:

```
@Configuration
 public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login.xhtml");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("login.xhtml");
    registry.addViewController("/jobs").setViewName("jobs.xhtml");

}
```

**successHandler**:

```
@Component
public class MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends 
SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

    if (savedRequest == null) {
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        return;
    }
    final String targetUrlParameter = getTargetUrlParameter();
    if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl() || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
        requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        return;
    }

    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}

public void setRequestCache(final RequestCache requestCache) {
    this.requestCache = requestCache;
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you send 200? I can't see it in your `MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. You do nothing. And why are you extenting `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, that is a class for redirection, not for returning 200.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. :-( @dur Why don't you give suggestions for changes instead of just pointing out errors? He is extending the class because of the example: https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security

Comment: @Vortilion: I didn't point out errors, I ask questions, because I didn't understand why OP think his code should work. Your link is helping.